# Scala design suggestion needed

Tags: scala, design-patterns

I would like to design a client that would talk to a **REST API**. I have implemented the bit that actually does call the **HTTP** methods on the server. I call this Layer, the API layer. Each operation the server exposes is encapsulated as one method in this layer. This method takes as input a `ClientContext` which contains all the needed information to make the HTTP method call on the server.

I'm now trying to set up the interface to this layer, let's call it `ClientLayer`. This interface will be the one any users of my client library should use to consume the services. When calling the interface, the user should create the `ClientContext`, set up the request parameters depending on the operation that he is willing to invoke. With the traditional **Java** approach, I would have a state on my `ClientLayer` object which represents the `ClientContext`:

For example:

```
public class ClientLayer {
 private static final ClientContext;
 ...
}
```

I would then have some constructors that would set up my `ClientContext`. A sample call would look like below:

```
ClientLayer client = ClientLayer.getDefaultClient();
client.executeMyMethod(client.getClientContext, new MyMethodParameters(...))
```

Coming to **Scala**, any suggestions on how to have the same level of simplicity with respect to the `ClientContext` instantiation while avoiding having it as a state on the `ClientLayer`?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid having it as state on the `ClientLayer`? That sounds like ordinary OO design, a perfectly legitimate style of programming in Scala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use factory pattern here:

```
object RestClient {
  class ClientContext
  class MyMethodParameters

  trait Client {
    def operation1(params: MyMethodParameters)
  }

  class MyClient(val context: ClientContext) extends Client {
    def operation1(params: MyMethodParameters) = {
      // do something here based on the context
    }
  }

  object ClientFactory {
    val defaultContext: ClientContext = // set it up here;

    def build(context: ClientContext): Client = {
      // builder logic here
      // object caching can be used to avoid instantiation of duplicate objects 
      context match {
        case _ => new MyClient(context)
      }
    }

    def getDefaultClient = build(defaultContext)

  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val client = ClientFactory.getDefaultClient
    client.operation1(new MyMethodParameters())
  }

}
```

Comment: Why did this answer get a -1 ?

Comment: That was by mistake. Sorry about that!